# Visual Studio 2017 ERROR: dep6200: bootstrapping failed

Tags: visual-studio, runtime-error, device, bootstrapping

I am trying to compile a C# project(.sln file) in Visual Studio 2017, but I keep geting an error as below:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found.
>   SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was
>   detected. Make sure a device is connected and powered on. [0x80131500]

I am not deploying any device, let alone a mobile device and the application I am loading was not even developed for mobiles, so I find this error rather strange.

After doing some research, especially on stackoverflow, I noticed that most of the people who have encountered this error are mentioning this in the context of emulators or turning on developers mode, which is not really applicable in my case.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. All I had to do was change the **build configuration**

from `"Debug - ARM"`

to `"Debug - x64"`

Comment: (－‸ლ) That'd do it!